# Zoom bot (Win SDK) seems to require a manual unmute to play audio?

Tags: audio, bots, video-streaming, zoom-sdk

I am having issues with sending raw audio in Zoom using the Windows Meeting SDK.

Using the [zoom SDK official samples](https://github.com/tanchunsiong/MSDK_RawDataDemos/tree/50f292d5cc859d9931a084b67fff912a964e7d8f) as a starting point I have the video and screenshare working as soon as my bot joins the call, however, I am running into issues with audio - **it only seems to work when the unmute button is pressed manually**, **is there a way to get the audio to play as soon as the bot joins?**

When I update the code to allow the bot to join with audio on, it still only seems to play the audio when I mute and then unmute the bot.

I noticed this `//TODO` comment in the code and was wondering if anyone has been able to solve this - https://github.com/tanchunsiong/MSDK_RawDataDemos/blob/50f292d5cc859d9931a084b67fff912a964e7d8f/SendAudioRawData/MSDK_SendAudioRawData.cpp#L61-L78

[image: Zoom comment indicating this is actually a bug/missing feature]

My overall goal is to send audio from the bot and so I’m open to other ideas of how to share it, if it is possible send as part of a screen share or another route!

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of this sample code. By the way this is not the official sample code from Zoom. I'm working on getting these samples into the official sample code here https://github.com/zoom/meetingsdk-linux-raw-recording-sample, and the repo which you have shared is work in progress

One of the way which I've tried, was to use the chat event handler to listen for specific commands and send the video. Some other ways which you might find useful, would be to use the event handlers triggered by on user join to send audio.

It would probably depend on the use case which you have.

I'm fairly active on https://devforum.zoom.us/
If you have any question regarding Zoom SDK, do tag me there, and I'll try my best to help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).